# How can i create thread in LoadRunner script with C#?

Tags: loadrunner

some thing like 
`Thread T = new Thread( new ThreadStart(ThreadPorc));`

i have tryed but ThreadProc not been called. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See .Net virtual User type developed in Visual Studio

Comment: i tried LoadRunner 12 with visual stdio 10 additional components and it works fine! but Virtual User Generator still has some problem when i write some complex code . but the result seems right!

Comment: C# = Develop in Visual Studio, not in VUGEN